# How to create partition on existing table in PostgreSQL10?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, postgresql-10

How can we create partitions on the existing table which has not defined with the portion key when it is created?

I have one large table and it has 1B+ records and 600GB in size.

1. Are there any new approaches to create a partition on the existing table?

   (OR)
2. Should we create a new table and copy data from old to new one?

Comment: The only option you have is 2. If you really need partitioning, I would strongly recommend to upgrade to Postgres 12. There were many substantial improvements to native partitioning since v10.

Comment: Thanks. Currently we have a server with v9.6 and upgrading to v10.7.

Comment: Then you should be upgrading straight to 12.

Comment: This cluster is service in ars rds and has only the option is to go 10x as of now. I think we can do it after that.